# Is there any way to send audio file to the speech-to-text recognition

Tags: android, file, wav, speech-recognition

I want the Android speech recognition system analysing audio file and not the default incoming voice from microphone.

Is there any way to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: I saw this link : http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/speech/recognition/MediaFileReader.html
that seems interesting but I don't now how I could reference to this class...

Comment: you can do this by first recording it from microphone then saving file as a byte array on runtime then decode this file from byte array to audio format file and input it to speech recognition system.

Comment: here is the soluton : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49980384/4648533)

Comment: have any solution android API version 28?

Answer (score 2):

cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid Just found that link sounds like someone has created a android version of Sphinx.

Looking at the Android api doing this doesn't seem to be supported.  (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html)

You might be able to using another API.

I know that Microsoft's C# api allows this but in order for that to be useful you would probably need to setup a server with a program you wrote record the sound file on the phone and then send it to the server.

CMUSphinx (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/) is written in Java so it might be possible to get it running on an Android device.  On that api you create a StreamSpeechReconizer.

```
StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
recognizer.startRecognition(new File("speech.wav").toURI().toURL());
SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
recognizer.stopRecognition();
```

I found this https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1730160 with a quick web search (google "speech recognition api accepts file") so there might be other services available on the web that would accept a file to be sent to them.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it works in a similar way to the chrome api - http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

As he has mentioned you can convert the microphone file into a .flac file and send it to the speech api, and you will get the same result. So you can use SOX and convert it yourself.

Hope it helps.
Dias

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work anymore, they took out the API