# how to convert text from audio clip?

Tags: android, audio, speech-to-text

I have an audio file link came from json file now I need to convert the audio clip to text and this text should compare with a speech to text in android programming.
how to convert this audio file to text, I had googled a lot, still didn't find the correct answer, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use two powerful natural language-oriented APIs offered by the Google Cloud Machine Learning platform: **Cloud Speech API** and **Cloud Natural Language API**. By using them together, you can create apps that can handle speech in a variety of widely spoken languages.

An application that can process speech must have the following capabilities:

1. It must be able to extract individual words from raw audio data.
2. It must be able to make educated guesses about the grammatical
   relationships between the words it has extracted.

The Cloud Speech and Cloud Natural Language APIs enable you to add the above capabilities to your Android app in a matter of minutes.